# Singularity container doesn't see files

Tags: server, singularity-container

I wanted to use singularity container on remote server, so I tried this command to create image:

`singularity build --fakeroot ....`

but when I enter the assembled container (`singularity shell name.container`) or try to run some program file thought exec, singularity can see, but can not open one folder. When I try to open it by `cd` there is this problem: `bash: cd: name_folder: No such file or directory`

Same container works perfect on my computer (`sudo singularity build ...`). Can you suggest anything, please?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the problem? Which files can't you see? Can you also include how you are running the container both on your computer and on the server? You can edit your question to include these things.